# What sounds deter sharks?

Tags: neuroscience, behaviour, marine-biology

Have any studies been done to find sounds that alienate sharks?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert_Gottfried

Comment: If you want to drive away, maybe it would be better with substances that trigger a particular taste.

Comment: Have you tried doing any of your own research on the topic??

Answer (score 1):

Sharks hear from 10-800hz.
Sharks jump out of water for fun, which makes  huge noise pressure next to their ears. Sound weapons aren't very renowned in Darpa or defence tech. i'd say, you play any kind of patterns to a shark at any frequency, you'll have a tough time upsetting it.  you may have a very good effect at attracting them from afar and delaying predatory response as they assess/avoid the prey. LF takes huge batteries compared to HF. curiously, dolpins hear up to 100khz, whales as low as 2-3 hz for booming across the ocean. precise answer here : https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?hl=en&q=shark+sonic+deterrent&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=

Comment: Todays best shark deterrents have z range of 5-10 meters and are magnetic and electric: https://prwire.com.au/pr/77309/worlds-first-boat-and-beach-long-range-shark-deterrents